# Image reconstruction with compressed sensing

Tags: python, image-compression, lasso-regression

I'm trying to code a demonstration of compressed sensing for my final year project but am getting poor image reconstruction when using the Lasso algorithm. I've relied on the following as a reference: http://www.pyrunner.com/weblog/2016/05/26/compressed-sensing-python/
However my code has some differences:

- I use scikit-learn to perform a lasso optimisation (basis pursuit) as opposed to using cvxpy to perform an l_1 minimisation with an equality constraint as in the article.
- I construct psi differently/more simply, testing seems to show that it's correct.
- I use a different package to read and write the image.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.fftpack as spfft
import scipy.ndimage as spimg
import imageio
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso


x_orig = imageio.imread('gt40.jpg', pilmode='L') # read in grayscale
x = spimg.zoom(x_orig, 0.2) #zoom for speed
ny,nx = x.shape

k = round(nx * ny * 0.5) #50% sample
ri = np.random.choice(nx * ny, k, replace=False) 
y = x.T.flat[ri] #y is the measured sample
# y = np.expand_dims(y, axis=1) ---- this doesn't seem to make a difference, was presumably required with cvxpy

psi = spfft.idct(np.identity(nx*ny), norm='ortho', axis=0) #my construction of psi
# psi = np.kron(
#     spfft.idct(np.identity(nx), norm='ortho', axis=0),
#     spfft.idct(np.identity(ny), norm='ortho', axis=0)
#     )
# psi = 2*np.random.random_sample((nx*ny,nx*ny)) - 1
theta = psi[ri,:] #equivalent to phi*psi

lasso = Lasso(alpha=0.001, max_iter=10000)
lasso.fit(theta, y)

s = np.array(lasso.coef_)
x_recovered = psi@s
x_recovered = x_recovered.reshape(nx, ny).T
x_recovered_final = x_recovered.astype('uint8') #recovered image is float64 and has negative values..

imageio.imwrite('gt40_recovered.jpg', x_recovered_final)
```

Unfortunately I'm not allowed to post images yet so here is a link to the original zoomed image, the image recovered with lasso and the image recovered with cvxpy (described later):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PObWQ.jpg

As you can see not only is the recovery poor but the image completely corrupted - the colours seem to be negative and the detail from the 50% sample lost. I think I've managed to track down the problem to the Lasso regression - it returns a vector that, when inverse transformed, has values that are not necessarily in the 0-255 range as expected for the image. So the conversion to from dtype float64 to uint8 is rather random (e.g. -55 becomes 255-55=200).

Following this I tried swapping out lasso for the same optimisation as in the article (minimising the l_1 norm subject to theta*s=y using cvxpy):

```py
import cvxpy as cvx


x_orig = imageio.imread('gt40.jpg', pilmode='L') # read in grayscale
x = spimg.zoom(x_orig, 0.2)
ny,nx = x.shape

k = round(nx * ny * 0.5)
ri = np.random.choice(nx * ny, k, replace=False)
y = x.T.flat[ri]

psi = spfft.idct(np.identity(nx*ny), norm='ortho', axis=0)
theta = psi[ri,:] #equivalent to phi*psi

#NEW CODE STARTS:

vx = cvx.Variable(nx * ny)
objective = cvx.Minimize(cvx.norm(vx, 1))
constraints = [theta@vx == y]
prob = cvx.Problem(objective, constraints)
result = prob.solve(verbose=True)

s = np.array(vx.value).squeeze()
x_recovered = psi@s
x_recovered = x_recovered.reshape(nx, ny).T
x_recovered_final = x_recovered.astype('uint8')

imageio.imwrite('gt40_recovered_altopt.jpg', x_recovered_final)
```

This took nearly 6 hours but finally I got a somewhat satisfactory result. However I would like to perform a demonstration of lasso if possible. Any help in getting the lasso to return appropriate values or somehow converting its result appropriately would be very much appreciated.